# Lexik Bundle Symfony 3

Tags: html, ajax, symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle

I use LexikAuthentication Bundle. When I try to make the UI using ajax for login_check, I get back the token in localStorage but when I try to login to my UI, I get `401 not authorization`.

This is my login_check:

```
function authenticate(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/login_check',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                '_username': $('#username').val(),
                '_password': $('#password').val()
            }),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json",
            access_token: "",
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != null && data != '') {
                    var token = "Bearer " + data.token;
                    console.log(token);
                    localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
                    }
            }
        });
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found the solution by my self.
The error was Here : localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
It should be like this : localStorage.setItem("Bearer " ,data.token);